# Using a 'mapping dictionary' to save entries in model with django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, mapping

i would like to pull info from different APIs that contains basically the same information and gather them in a generic model.

How could I create a mapping to make the relations easier?

For example, at the moment I have a 'Contact_API_A' model:

```
class ContactAPIA(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

a 'Contact_API_B' model:

```
class ContactAPIB(models.Model):
    UUID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

These models contain the naming conventions of the APIs.

and a 'Contact' model which is using my own naming convention:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In my view I am fetching the contacts from the respective APIs & saving them in their models using a dictionary.

views:

```
def get_contacts_API_A(request):
    ...
    contacts_api_a = API_A.contacts()

    for contact in contacts_api_a:
        contact_api_a_dict = {
            'id':contact.id,
            'name':contact.name}

        c = ContactAPIA(**contact_api_a_dict)
        c.save()
```

in a second step i am inserting those contaccts into my generic contact model.
views:

```
def contacts_api_a_to_contacts(request):
    ...
    contacts = ContactAPIA.objects.all()

    for contact in contacts:
        contact_api_a_to_contacts_dict = {
            'id':contact.id,
            'full_name':contact.name,
            'source':'api_a'}

        c = Contact(**contact_api_a_to_contact_dict)
        c.save()
```

The actual contact dictionaries contain far more information so i tried to move them to a 'mapping.py' file and importing that file into views. 
When doing so i get the error that the name 'contact' is not defined.

mapping.py:

```
contact_api_a_dict = {
        'id':contact.id,
        'name':contact.name}
```

the error makes sense to me since 'contact' is not defined. How could i still use such a mapping file to keep my views tidier and have a better overview of the different fields?

Or is there another way of mapping the info e.g. with a mapping model or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some constants and dictionary comprehensions to extract your data.  For example:

```
MAPPING = (
  ('id', 'id'),
  ('full_name', 'name'),
)

# ...

contact_api_a_to_contact_dict = {target: getattr(contact, src) for target, src in MAPPING}
```